# Server Side Job System in PHP

Tags: php, cron, task, jobs

I want to know what your opinion about running scripts in server side in PHP!

Actually my idea is:

```
EXECUTE CRON(){
   IF TASKS TO DO {
     RUN PHP SCRIPT FOR USER MISSING THIS TASK in BACKGROUND
   }
}
```

The script to run for each user is kinda long, so I need to keep using less resources possible for this running script.

Iv tried using `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, etc without success, now using a JAVASCRIPT that make my file run but it's still unstable.

What you guys think is the best solution to keep my system executing tasks in the background and keep sending me the reports of the task being executed, or manage to stop them and resume when I want..?

Many thanks :)

Comment: And why do you need more than cron? Just put the tasks need to be run in cron for eash user and if they fail send the output to yourself or who ever needs it.

Comment: how did shell_exec(), exec() fail?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$do_break = false;
do
{
  if(check_new_task())
  {
    do_task();
  }
  else if($break)
  {
    $do_break = true;
  } else
  {
    sleep(sleep_duration);
  }
} while(!$do_break);
```

you can run your script from ssh using screens

```
screen -S screenname
```

and run php script once in this screen
remember you have to care about task termination manually or ...

Comment: not that this is not a real code , I meant $break , not break . thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Gearman is necessary to install on the server.

If simpler tasks or you not have permission on server, you can execute a php script with CRON via CURL:

```
* * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://example.com/tasks.php
```